# LinearLayoutManager cannot use in Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an error on my `LinearLayoutManager`, when I run this code its says

```
error: incompatible types: NotificationFragment cannot be converted to Context
```

Here is my code NotificationFragment.java

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NotificationAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<NotificationModel> notificationModelArrayList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification,container,false);

        addData();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)   getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        adapter = new NotificationAdapter(notificationModelArrayList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(NotificationFragment.this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    void addData(){
        notificationModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        notificationModelArrayList.add(new NotificationModel("Event 1", "1 January 2019", "Surabaya"));
        notificationModelArrayList.add(new NotificationModel("Event 2", "1 January 2019", "Surabaya"));
        notificationModelArrayList.add(new NotificationModel("Event 3", "1 January 2019", "Surabaya"));
        notificationModelArrayList.add(new NotificationModel("Event 4", "1 January 2019", "Surabaya"));
    }

}
```

The error is on

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(NotificationFragment.this);
```

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't cast a `Fragment` to a `Context`.

Edit this line:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(NotificationFragment.this);
```

to:

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
```

or

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

Remember to check null for `getContext()` or `getActivity()` before using it.

For your new question from the comment below, just bring the return statement to the end of function:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification,container,false);

    addData();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)  view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    adapter = new NotificationAdapter(notificationModelArrayList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(NotificationFragment.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the error is gone, but there is another new error, pointed on "addData();" its say "error: unreachable statement" and "error: missing return statement"

Answer (score 1):

Use getActivity() instead of NotificationFragment.this

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```